# What's the recommended way to deal with Singletons cleanup in Android (Kotlin)?

Tags: android, singleton, kotlin

I have been having some weird issues in my Android app when closing it via back key and reentering, and found they are happening because variables in 2 Singleton classes I have are never re-initializing (The issue doesn't happen if manually killing the app from task manager).

Even after I call finish explicitly on Main activity onBackPressed and I can see onDestroy is called, the Singletons are still in memory.

I decided to do manual cleanup of these Singletons before destroying my Activity, the problem is using Kotlin I would need to make all their member variables nullable (?) and it would be a lot of hassle to remember to assign null to every variable, so for now I opted to handle the instantiation of the Singleton like this and just make null the whole instance while cleaning:

```
class SingletonName {

    companion object {
        private var _instance: SingletonName ? = null
        private var instance: SingletonName ?
            get() {
                if (_instance == null) {
                    _instance = SingletonName ()
                }
                return _instance
            }
            set(value) {
                _instance = value
            }

        @JvmStatic fun get(): SingletonName {
            return instance!! //avoid having to deal with nullable value in client code
        }
    }

    //need to make sure to call this before destroying main activity
    fun cleanup() {
        instance = null
    }
}
```

Client use:

```
SingletonName.get().somefunc()
```

These seems more involved than it should, and I know this is not even thread safe, but keep in mind that simply using the 'object' keyword instead of 'class' will not work, as it will prevent any initialization taking place the second time I run the app (the constructor is not being called again and I can't force destroy the instance).

This makes me think it might be worth looking into Android dependency injection but I feel like at least one of my Singletons really needs to be accessed on a lot of places so it might not be an elegant solution either (Probably need to refactor it into smaller functionalities).

The main issue here is the way android handles destruction but I guess I can't change that, I don't see any reason why it keeps all the static values of non activity classes if the application activities are already destroyed.

The question is how do you deal with this cases regardless of the language used? or what do you think are the best practices in this case?

Edit: Actually I just did a test with Dagger 2, and the same problem happens, if I use @Provides and @Singleton, the values of member variables on the provided object the second time launching the app are not null so I guess this needs to be dealt with explicitly unless I am missing some more annotations to tell Dagger that the instance should be released at the end of the app life-cycle.

Comment: You could have a method like `recreate` or something to reinitialize your singleton

Comment: The whole approach looks weird. If you need this 'singleton' only when Activity is visilbe, just create an object inside Activity.

Comment: @Miha_x64 the thing is I need the singleton throughout the entire life of the app, yes I guess having a recreate at the beginning will be the same as having a cleanup at the end, but the problem is the same, need to make sure to reset each member variable.

Comment: `android.app.Application` will exist for the entire life of the app. If you want an object which will live shorter, with UI, and survive configuration changes, consider using `onRetainCustomNonConfigurationInstance`.

Comment: If that state should be "cleaned up", it's probably tied to an Activity or Service and should not be stored in a global singleton. Also, there is no such thing as "closing" an Android app. The system decides when to kill it.

Answer (score 1):

creating Singleton in kotlin is as easy as following

Take following as an example

No need to create class explicitly, just do the following

```
 object MySingleton   {

      fun myFunction() {

        }
    }
```

And call it like

```
MySingleton.myFunction()
```

you read more about singleton in kotlin from its doc https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-declarations

Comment: @Ascorbin Are you sure you know Kotlin? This is how singleton is created in Kotlin. You can check Kotlin official Documentation.

Comment: Whoops, sorry! You're right, I missed the object keyword. You could remove the database stuff (because it's irrelevant here), highlight the object keyword and point to the specific part of the link you posted: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-declarations

Comment: @Ascorbin It is alright. I have removed the database part. And I have also changed the link to point it to the specific part. Would you mind upvoting my answer now?

Comment: @v4_adi The problem with object is, if you put an init block, you will see that it is only being executed the first time, after closing app via back key and relaunching it no init code will be called, whatever was in the member variables is still going to be there, so I will still need to make sure to reset each member variable at some point.